# Convert a matrix to a list of matrices based on a vector of row lengths

Tags: r, matrix, split, subset

I want to split a large matrix, *mt*, into a list of sub-matrices, *res*. The number of rows for each sub-matrix is specified by a vector, *len*.

For example,

```
> mt=matrix(c(1:20),ncol=2)
> mt
      [,1] [,2]
 [1,]    1   11
 [2,]    2   12
 [3,]    3   13
 [4,]    4   14
 [5,]    5   15
 [6,]    6   16
 [7,]    7   17
 [8,]    8   18
 [9,]    9   19
[10,]   10   20

lens=c(2,3,5)
```

What I want is a function *some_function*, that can offer the following result,

```
> res=some_function(mt,lens)

> res
[[1]]
     [,1] [,2]
[1,]    1   11
[2,]    2   12

[[2]]
     [,1] [,2]
[1,]    3   13
[2,]    4   14
[3,]    5   15

[[3]]
     [,1] [,2]
[1,]    6   16
[2,]    7   17
[3,]    8   18
[4,]    9   19
[5,]   10   20
```

Speed is a big concern. The faster, the better!

Many thanks!

Comment: Certainly. Would you like some coffee while you wait?

Comment: look at `?split()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A function to create index based on length of each value and split the matrix.

```
mt <- matrix(c(1:20), ncol=2)

# Two arguments: m - matrix, len - length of each group
m_split <- function(m, len){
  index <- 1:sum(len)
  group <- rep(1:length(len), times = len)
  index_list <- split(index, group)
  mt_list <- lapply(index_list, function(vec) mt[vec, ])
  return(mt_list)
}

m_split(mt, c(2, 3, 5))
$`1`
     [,1] [,2]
[1,]    1   11
[2,]    2   12

$`2`
     [,1] [,2]
[1,]    3   13
[2,]    4   14
[3,]    5   15

$`3`
     [,1] [,2]
[1,]    6   16
[2,]    7   17
[3,]    8   18
[4,]    9   19
[5,]   10   20
```

#### Update

I used the following code to compare the performance of each method in this post.

```
library(microbenchmark)
library(data.table)

# Test case from @missuse
mt <- matrix(c(1:20000000),ncol=10)
lens <- c(20000,15000,(nrow(mt)-20000-15000))

# Functions from @Damiano Fantini
split.df <- function(mt, lens) {
  fac <- do.call(c, lapply(1:length(lens), (function(i){ rep(i, lens[i])})))
  split(as.data.frame(mt), f = fac)
}

split.mat <- function(mt, lens) {
  fac <- do.call(c, lapply(1:length(lens), (function(i){ rep(i, lens[i])})))
  lapply(unique(fac), (function(i) {mt[fac==i,]}))
}

# Benchmarking
microbenchmark(m1 = {m_split(mt, lens)}, # @ycw's method 
               m2 = {pam = rep(1:length(lens), times = lens)
                     split(data.table(mt), pam)}, # @missuse's data.table method
               m3 = {split.df(mt, lens)}, # @Damiano Fantini's data frame method
               m4 = {split.mat(mt, lens)}) # @Damiano Fantini's matrix method

Unit: milliseconds
 expr      min       lq     mean   median       uq      max neval
   m1 167.6896 209.7746 251.0932 230.5920 274.9347 555.8839   100
   m2 402.3415 497.2397 554.1094 547.9603 599.7632 787.4112   100
   m3 552.8548 657.6245 719.2548 711.4123 769.6098 989.6779   100
   m4 166.6581 203.6799 249.2965 235.5856 275.4790 547.4927   100
```

As we can see, `m1` and `m4` are the fastest, while there are almost no differences between them, which means it is not needed to convert the `matrix` to a `data frame` or a `data.table` especially if the OP will keep working on the `matrix`. Working directly on the `matrix` (`m1` and `m4`) should be sufficient.

Comment: I have written a function exactly like yours. But I was not sure if it was the fastest. Thanks for the comparison and your efforts!

Comment: I am glad to help.

Answer (score 2):

If you are OK working with data.frames instead of matrices, you might build a grouping factor/vector according to `lens` and then use `split()`. Alternatively, use this grouping vector to subset your matrix and return a list. In this example, I wrapped the two solutions into two functions: .

```
# your data
mt=matrix(c(1:20),ncol=2)
lens=c(2,3,5)

# based on split
split.df <- function(mt, lens) {
  fac <- do.call(c, lapply(1:length(lens), (function(i){ rep(i, lens[i])})))
  split(as.data.frame(mt), f = fac)
}
split.df(mt, lens)

# based on subsetting
split.mat <- function(mt, lens) {
  fac <- do.call(c, lapply(1:length(lens), (function(i){ rep(i, lens[i])})))
  lapply(unique(fac), (function(i) {mt[fac==i,]}))
}
split.mat(mt, lens)
```

This second option is about ~10 times faster than the other one according to microbenchmark

```
library(microbenchmark)
microbenchmark({split.df(mt, lens)}, times = 1000)
# median = 323.743 microseconds
microbenchmark({split.mat(mt, lens)}, times = 1000)
# median = 31.7645 microseconds
```

Answer (score 1):

One aproach is using `split`, however it can operate on vectors and data.frames so you need to convert the matrix - `data.table` should be efficient

```
mt=matrix(c(1:20),ncol=2)
lens=c(2,3,5)
pam = rep(1:length(lens), times = lens)
library(data.table)
mt_split <- split(data.table(mt), pam)
mt_split
#output
$`1`
   V1 V2
1:  1 11
2:  2 12

$`2`
   V1 V2
1:  3 13
2:  4 14
3:  5 15

$`3`
   V1 V2
1:  6 16
2:  7 17
3:  8 18
4:  9 19
5: 10 20
```

Checking speed

```
mt=matrix(c(1:20000000),ncol=10)
lens=c(20000,15000,(nrow(mt)-20000-15000))
pam = rep(1:length(lens), times = lens)

system.time(split(data.table(mt), pam))
#output   
user  system elapsed 
0.75    0.20    0.96
```